# "yum repolist" showing repo list but there is NO repo file in /etc/yum.repo.d

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

Could any one look into the issue and help ?

I have a Red Hat server which has Red Hat subscription and I tried to get all Security patches list using `/usr/bin/yum list-security --security`.
After executing above command, I see all the packages that listed are SuSE packages. Not sure why.

```
[root@test ~]# /usr/bin/yum list-security --security 
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
slessp3-bash-9740 security bash-3.2-147.20.1.x86_64
slessp3-bash-9780 security bash-3.2-147.22.1.x86_64
slessp3-binutils-201501-10214 security binutils-2.23.1-0.23.15.x86_64
```

Tried to verify the yum repository using `yum repolist` and I see the SuSE repo is enabled. But I didn't see repo file under `yum.repos.d` to disable.

```
[root@test ~]# yum repolist 
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
repo id repo name status
rhel-source Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5Server - Source enabled: 5,076
rpmforge RHEL 5Server - RPMforge.net - dag enabled: 11,403
sles11-sp3-pool-x86_64 SLES11-SP3-Pool for x86_64 enabled: 2,862
sles11-sp3-suse-manager-tools-x86_64 SLES11-SP3-SUSE-Manager-Tools x86_64 enabled: 121
sles11-sp3-updates-x86_64 SLES11-SP3-Updates for x86_64 enabled: 3,618
repolist: 23,080

[root@test yum.repos.d]# ls -lrt
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 561 Jan 14 2015 rhel-debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1128 Mar 15 2012 rpmforge.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 728 Mar 15 2012 mirrors-rpmforge-testing
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 739 Mar 15 2012 mirrors-rpmforge
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 222 Sep 17 12:20 rhel-source.repo
```

Comment: I would run `yum clean all`, `yum repolist -v` and look at the `Repo-filename` fields.

Comment: This question seems unrelated to programming so [SU], [SF] or [unix.se] might be more suitable places to ask this than [SO].

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. We need to verify if serverURL in "up2date" file is a RedHat public URL or not. If not, then comment out the existing URL and give Redhat public URL under /etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date file. Now if we run yum repolist, then we can see only repo which we have repo files under yum.repos.d. If you find any ssl ceert issue after running yum repolist, then make sure we have the correct sslCACert path under up2date file.